# Combine list of data frames of differing length by row names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a list (df) of data frames of differing lengths, indexed by years such that a proxy of the data looks like:

```
df

  $df1          
         X..i..
  1999     10
  1998     13 
  1997     14

 $df2
         X..i..
 1999      20
 1998      11

 $df3
         X..i..
 1999      17
 1998       8
 1997       9
 1996      19
```

I would like to combine these data frames to a single data frame using and preserving the index/rownames

So that:

```
df_all
 Index     df1   df2   df3
  1999      10    20    17
  1998      13    11     8
  1997      14    n/a    9
  1996      n/a   n/a   19
```

Edit:

```
smalldflist <- lapply(bai_df, function(i) head(i, 10))
dput(smalldflist)
```

Produces the following output:

structure(list(IN_DonaldsonWoods_QUAL.txt = structure(list(X..i.. = c(4.5528243479162, 
32.6474339976978, 52.7116018957456, 170.932582874866, 227.0430440174, 
191.462399206825, 226.94053541991, 274.854835798233, 336.457600434571, 
409.132933511232)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1725", 
"1726", "1727", "1728", "1729", "1730", "1731", "1732", "1733", 
"1734"), class = "data.frame"), IN_DonaldsonWoods_QURU.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(4.33729067152776, 5.72878688080428, 13.0247658962315, 
    22.0205798005054, 25.9885943197615, 18.9273551074104, 43.5197887382031, 
    58.2775710248884, 72.9225976242458, 73.0466756114972)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1827", 
"1828", "1829", "1830", "1831", "1832", "1833", "1834", "1835", 
"1836"), class = "data.frame"), IN_DonaldsonWoods_QUVE.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(7.87253273859391, 18.9481296742303, 42.5055176960097, 
    62.9980951594496, 88.906442207264, 74.2523230533691, 106.911242713809, 
    152.445167763284, 192.399603839633, 221.263660216113)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1731", 
"1732", "1733", "1734", "1735", "1736", "1737", "1738", "1739", 
"1740"), class = "data.frame"), IN_LillyDickey_QUAL.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(8.29576810088555, 17.2934968058816, 31.2091720401804, 
    33.8966066349882, 47.6496887415004, 32.9921546763907, 82.2281435044324, 
    108.068226885475, 103.894002151431, 110.255812097949)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1863", 
"1864", "1865", "1866", "1867", "1868", "1869", "1870", "1871", 
"1872"), class = "data.frame"), IN_LillyDickey_QUMO.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(3.42413493048312, 8.0847630303073, 19.6833503197648, 
    13.791136218324, 21.4638165402601, 30.6707376168741, 30.8789937938806, 
    26.8661212585221, 24.0732956549621, 29.7872997715364)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1867", 
"1868", "1869", "1870", "1871", "1872", "1873", "1874", "1875", 
"1876"), class = "data.frame"), IN_Pioneers_QUAL.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(9.14340435634345, 23.5108626053757, 33.8507393822465, 
    46.1027716604662, 57.5247983011993, 50.5892015892391, 92.2448163706925, 
    225.832932372368, 278.367628044195, 193.931508820174)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1817", 
"1818", "1819", "1820", "1821", "1822", "1823", "1824", "1825", 
"1826"), class = "data.frame"), IN_Pioneers_QURU.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(122.443727611702, 658.649900930018, 830.471777578934, 
    843.357139228152, 1725.6495913006, 1244.38668477703, 973.00892131628, 
    1294.7441782001, 1717.18570086886, 1676.63841798444)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1861", 
"1862", "1863", "1864", "1865", "1866", "1867", "1868", "1869", 
"1870"), class = "data.frame"), OH_JohnsonWoods_QUAL.txt = structure(list(
    X..i.. = c(1.9113449704439, 3.39794661412248, 5.32688450342693, 
    6.41921626908008, 11.0307601252838, 13.0825342873437, 15.843680070585, 
    16.885746353779, 20.1011664347289, 19.853294774361)), .Names = "X..i..", row.names = c("1626", 
"1627", "1628", "1629", "1630", "1631", "1632", "1633", "1634", 
"1635"), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("IN_DonaldsonWoods_QUAL.txt", 
"IN_DonaldsonWoods_QURU.txt", "IN_DonaldsonWoods_QUVE.txt", "IN_LillyDickey_QUAL.txt", 
"IN_LillyDickey_QUMO.txt", "IN_Pioneers_QUAL.txt", "IN_Pioneers_QURU.txt", 
"OH_JohnsonWoods_QUAL.txt"))

Comment: Could you paste the result of `dput(df)`? This will make it easier to work with your data and work on a solution.

Comment: @beigel The data I've provided is only a proxy. I'm working with large datasets

Comment: Create a smaller df list like 10 rows X 3 cols: `smalldfList <- lapply(dfList, function(i) head(i, 10)[c("col1", "col2", "col3")])`. Then `dput(smalldfList)`, then post that gobblyegook here (trust us we know how to use it).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reduce` to `merge` multiple data frames. Set `all = TRUE` which adds NAs when no matches occurs. Note df is the list of data frames as you have set up, and `by` indicates the column used for merging.  Therefore in your list of data frames, "Index" should be the name of the year column in each data frame.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="Index", all=TRUE), df)
```

And thanks to @jazzuro providing sample data, here is the equivalent solution using `Reduce` in base R. In this sample set the column used for merging `by="year"`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 1998, 1997),
              value = c(10, 13, 14))

df2 <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 1998),
              value = c(20, 11))

df3 <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 1998, 1997, 1996),
              value = c(17, 8, 9, 19))
df <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
df_merge  <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="year", all=TRUE), df)
colnames(df_merge) <- c("Index", names(df))

#   Index df1 df2 df3
# 1 1996  NA  NA  19
# 2 1997  14  NA   9
# 3 1998  13  11   8
# 4 1999  10  20  17
```

Comment: That is producing the following error: Error in f(init, x[[i]]): unused argument (x[[i]])

Comment: It is hard for me to troubleshoot your error when I don't have your data is a usable format. As @beigel advised, you need to paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question where df is your proxy data which should have the same structure as your real data

Comment: The output of dput(df) exceeds the character limit for the body of a question

Comment: `df` should just be a subset of your data, not your full data.  You have a 3-, 2-, 4- element list of data frames in your example, that should not exceed the character limit.

Comment: Sorry, the data I originally provided was proxy, not subset. That is, it was only meant to represent my data

Comment: Your smalldfList `dput()` shows you have no *Index* column. Do note this is not Python pandas dataframe but R dataframes that have no concept of index.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data you need only in global environment, you could try the following. First, you collect unique years in all data frames and create a master data frame, which includes unique years only. Then, you put all data frames in a list and merge each of them with `master`. Since you have the master data frame in `temp`, you remove it. Finally, you bind all data frames and change the long format to a wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create a data frame with all unique years

master <- data.frame(year = mget(ls()) %>%
                            sapply(`[`, 1) %>%
                            as_vector %>% 
                            unique)

# Merge each data frame with the master df
temp <- mget(ls()) %>%
        lapply(function(x){full_join(x, master, by = "year")})

# Remove the master df in the list
temp[["master"]] <- NULL

# Bind all dfs and make it wide.
bind_rows(temp, .id = "data") %>%
spread(key = data, value = value)

#  year df1 df2 df3
#1 1996  NA  NA  19
#2 1997  14  NA   9
#3 1998  13  11   8
#4 1999  10  20  17
```

DATA

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 1998, 1997),
                  value = c(10, 13, 14))

df2 <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 1998),
                  value = c(20, 11))

df3 <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 1998, 1997, 1996),
                  value = c(17, 8, 9, 19))
```

Comment: Ben, please see what @jazzurro graciously typed up for you as sample data, this is considered a reproducible example, it is in a form users can simply paste and use to answer your question and troubleshoot errors :)

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider the chain merge as @Djork shows but make sure you create an actual column named, *Index* equal to `rownames()`. Also, rename the `X..1` column according to *df#* which also avoids the duplicate column warning during merges. Below *dfs* is equivalent to posted *smalldflist*:

```
dfs <- lapply(seq_along(dfs), function(i){
        dfs[[i]]$Index = rownames(dfs[[i]])        # CREATE INDEX
        colnames(dfs[[i]])[1] <- paste0("df", i)   # RENAME X..1 COLUMN

        return(dfs[[i]])
})

dfs[[1]]
#             df1 Index
# 1725   4.552824  1725
# 1726  32.647434  1726
# 1727  52.711602  1727
# 1728 170.932583  1728
# 1729 227.043044  1729
# 1730 191.462399  1730
# 1731 226.940535  1731
# 1732 274.854836  1732
# 1733 336.457600  1733
# 1734 409.132934  1734

finaldf <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="Index", all=TRUE), dfs)

finaldf
#    Index    df1     df2     df3     df4    df5    df6   df7        df8
# 1   1626     NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA    NA   1.911345
# 2   1627     NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA    NA   3.397947
# 3   1628     NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA    NA   5.326885
# 4   1629     NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA    NA   6.419216
# 5   1630     NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA    NA  11.030760
# ...
```